# MS Access VBA Run-time Error '13' Type Mismatch when looking up folder/subfolder names

Tags: vba, ms-access

Here's the VBA code I'm using in MS Access (from Microsoft's support site - no edits):

**

```
Private Sub Command3_Click()
         Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
         Dim f As Folder, sf As Folder, path As String
         'Initialize path.
         path = Environ("windir")
         'Get a reference to the Folder object.
         Set f = fso.GetFolder(path)
         'Iterate through subfolders.
         For Each sf In f.SubFolders
           Debug.Print sf.Name
         Next
      End Sub
```

**

I have also created the directory "C:\Test" and tried path = "C:\Test\" and path = "C:\Test"
I am aware that the reference "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" needs to be enabled - and it is.

The code compiles without error.
Despite the above, I'm still getting Run-time Error '13' Type Mismatch when I try to run it.

Is there anything else I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your code as is works for me. What line is the error occurring on?

Comment: Can't repro either based on the provided info. What other code is there in your DB?

Comment: Which line has the error?

Comment: Sorry for not getting back sooner. Thank you so much for responding.
The error occurs at:
Set f = fso.GetFolder(path)

Answer (score 0):

Try late binding

```
      Private Sub Command3_Click()
       Dim fso As Object
     Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

      Dim f As Object, sf As Object, path As String
     'Initialize path.
     path = Environ("windir")
     'Get a reference to the Folder object.
     Set f = fso.GetFolder(path)
     'Iterate through subfolders.
     For Each sf In f.SubFolders
       Debug.Print sf.Name
     Next
  End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried late binding. 
Now, I'm getting Error '91 - Object Variable or With Block Variable not set.

I did some looking around to find out why and I'm stumped. I also tested with path = "C:\Test\" and "C:\Test" 

I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: It looks like the scripting library is not registered on your system.
So try to follow the answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56396335/failure-to-set-fso-createobject-with-exceltoword-add-in